# I get "TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null" when trying to test get all route?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, mysql-workbench

I am building a login system. When I try to get all users from MySQL DB to test the system  and I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at firstchar (E:\vs work\mysql signup login system\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:176:37)
    at parse (E:\vs work\mysql signup login system\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:79:19)
    at E:\vs work\mysql signup login system\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (E:\vs work\mysql signup login system\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
    at done (E:\vs work\mysql signup login system\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (E:\vs work\mysql signup login system\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:388:22)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1336:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
```

what's wrong????

that's my code**

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  db.query('SELECT * FROM users', 
  (err, rows, fields) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    } 
      res.send({rows})

    
  })
});

//* sign up route 

router.post('/sign-up', userValidation.validateRegister, (req, res, next)=>{
  db.query(
    `SELECT * FROM users WHERE LOWER(user_name) = LOWER(${db.escape(req.body.user_name)})
      OR LOWER(email) = LOWER (${db.escape(req.body.email)});`,
    
       (err, result) => {
        if(result.length) {
          return res.status(409).send({msg:'already in use email/username'})
        } else {

          // ? username is available => hash the pass

          bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash)=>{
            if(err){
              return res.status(500).send({msg: err})
            } else {

              let email = req.body.email

             //? has hashed pw => add to database 

             db.query(
               `INSERT INTO USERS (id,user_name,email,password,registrated) 
                    VALUES ('${uuid.v4()}', ${db.escape(req.body.user_name)},'${email}', 
                    ${db.escape(hash)}, now())`,
                (err, result) =>{
                  if (err) {
                    throw err
                    return res.status(400).send({msg: err})
                  }

                  return res.status(201).send({msg: "Registered!!"})
                }
                


               )
      
            }
          })
        }
      }
      
      )

})
```

Comment: Looks like the error is not happening in this part of code

Comment: can you explain how please?

Comment: Because you are not trying to access an antry of object(null in this case). It could be happening in the callback functions. Try console.log() at a few points. This way you can know until which part the code is running

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  db.query('SELECT * FROM users', 
  (err, rows, fields) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    } 
   if(!rows) throw 'rows not found !'
      res.json({rows});

  })
});
```

Comment: gave me  same TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

Each query is a promise. It takes some time until you get the result of your request to retrieve data from the database. In your code, you are trying to send `rows` before you get them back as a response. So you need to wait until you get data back from db.

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const result = await db.query('SELECT * FROM users', (err, rows, fields) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    } 
  })
  res.send(result)
});
```

I recommend using `async` and `await` when querying.